# SSIS: Exporting column properties from an ODBC Source?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

Maybe there's a better way entirely to do this, but I'm trying to create data flow packages from our company's live database to staging tables on a dev sql server. To copy the data a table with matching columns and datatypes needs to already exist on the server so that it can be selected as a destination in SSIS. I have found creating these destination tables to be quite tedious. I don't have any schema documentation to lean on. And so far, the only way I've discovered to find the source table datatypes is in the Advanced Editor of the ODBC Source tool, from which I have to transcribe them line-by-line into an SQL create table statement.

Is there a better way to accurately create these staging tables? Is there any way to export these column properties from the ODBC Source tool?

[image]

Comment: I've not worked with SSIS for years but maybe connect it to 
a temporary newly created destination and then use the method shown here to get a `CREATE TABLE`? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9068/write-data-to-a-destination-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: You can query SSIS *.dtsx files via XQuery. Overall, they are just XML files.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky This was helpful. I didn't bother with XQuery, but I copied the relevant section out of the .dtsx file and opened it in Excel. Thank you